# How to add a code for an output

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am working on this project in .net. When you go over to the browser you will see five different restaurants and the button below says to change color and if you click on that you are able to change it. What I am trying to do is beside the name of the restaurant have the address, phone number but I really don't know how to code it in. I'm sure I do but my mind is not remembering how to do it. Below are my codes..

Here is my class code:

```
Public Class Restaurant

Private _Id As Integer
Public Property Id() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Id
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _Id = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _Name As String
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _Location As String
Public Property Location() As String
    Get
        Return _Location
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Location = value
    End Set
End Property


Private _Stars As Integer
Public Property Stars() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Stars
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _Stars = value
    End Set
End Property



Private _PhoneNumber As Integer
Public Property PhoneNumber() As String   ' Allows "-", ".", "x" in number
    Get
        Return _PhoneNumber
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _PhoneNumber = value
    End Set
End Property





Public Sub Restaurant()

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' This Function simulates getting data from a Database
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function GetFavoriteRestaurants() As List(Of Restaurant)
    Dim favRestaurants As List(Of Restaurant) = Nothing
    favRestaurants = New List(Of Restaurant)

    favRestaurants.Add(New Restaurant)
    favRestaurants(0).Id = 0
    favRestaurants(0).Name = "Carabbas"
    favRestaurants(0).Location = "North Canton"
    favRestaurants(0).Stars = 3
    favRestaurants(0).PhoneNumber = 330 - 966 - 242


    favRestaurants.Add(New Restaurant)
    favRestaurants(1).Id = 1
    favRestaurants(1).Name = "Peter Shears"
    favRestaurants(1).Location = "Canton"
    favRestaurants(1).Stars = 4
    favRestaurants(1).PhoneNumber = 330 - 522 - 8300


    favRestaurants.Add(New Restaurant)
    favRestaurants(2).Id = 2
    favRestaurants(2).Name = "Salsitas"
    favRestaurants(2).Location = "Kent"
    favRestaurants(2).Stars = 2
    favRestaurants(2).PhoneNumber = 330 - 673 - 8874

    favRestaurants.Add(New Restaurant)
    favRestaurants(3).Id = 3
    favRestaurants(3).Name = "Ruby Tuesday"
    favRestaurants(3).Location = "North Canton"
    favRestaurants(3).Stars = 4
    favRestaurants(3).PhoneNumber = 330 - 434 - 232

    favRestaurants.Add(New Restaurant)
    favRestaurants(4).Id = 4
    favRestaurants(4).Name = "OutBack SteakHouse"
    favRestaurants(4).Location = " Canton"
    favRestaurants(4).Stars = 4
    favRestaurants(4).PhoneNumber = 330 - 493 - 9515

    Return favRestaurants
End Function

 End Class
```

Here is my other code:

```
 <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="RestaurantVB._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Lab W8</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        //I built in some of our HTML5 code from last week
        function browserHtml5Test() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("html5Test");
            if (canvas == null || canvas.getContext == null) {
                document.getElementById("canvasReport").style.color = "Red";
                document.getElementById("canvasReport").innerHTML = "HTML5 NOT Supported";
            }
            document.getElementById("canvasReport").innerHTML = "HTML5 Supported!";
        }

        function changeStyles() {
            //Get the Id of this particular item. Here we don't have to change the styles.
            //We could make a call to a database via ajax since we have the id that is stored
            //in the database.
            var tmp = document.getElementById("rest0");
            if (tmp != null) {
                tmp.style.color = "green";
            }

            tmp = document.getElementById("rest1");
            if (tmp != null) {
                tmp.style.color = "green";
            }

            tmp = document.getElementById("rest2");
            if (tmp != null) {
                tmp.style.color = "green";
            }

            tmp = document.getElementById("rest3");
            if (tmp != null) {
                tmp.style.color = "green";
            }

            tmp = document.getElementById("rest4");
            if (tmp != null) {
                tmp.style.color = "green";
            }

            tmp = document.getElementById("rest5");
            if (tmp != null) {
                tmp.style.color = "green";
            }
            //Yes these could have been done via loop.
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #TextArea1
        {
            width: 244px;
        }
        #Select1
        {
            width: 226px;
        }
        #Text1
        {
            width: 151px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="browserHtml5Test();" style="height: 340px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="canvasReport" style="color: Blue; margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
    <div>
        <% 
            For Each r As RestaurantVB.Restaurant In _restaurants
                Response.Write(String.Format("<div id=""rest{0}"">{1}</div>", r.Id, r.Name))
            Next

        %>
        &nbsp;
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <input type="button" value="Change Styles" onclick="changeStyles();" /></div>

    <canvas id="html5Test” width="150" height="150"></canvas>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My question would be can someone help me understand how to write the phone number and address beside the restaurant so that way they all show up.

Comment: Try to reduce your code to the essential parts when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
For Each r As RestaurantVB.Restaurant In _restaurants
    Response.Write(String.Format("<div id=""rest{0}"">{1}<br />", r.Id, r.Name))
    Response.Write(String.Format("{0}, {1}</div>", r.Location, r.PhoneNumber))
Next
```

Basically just adding another line under the original one with the address and phone num. If you add the extra data to the same line it might get pretty long, depending how long the address is...